# Microsoft SSO fail in my teams tab and task module

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

> "error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'.
> This is the error I am getting while exchanging my client side token to server-side token.
> I gave all additional consent.

```
      client_id: ****,
      client_secret: ***,
      grant_type: 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
      assertion: clientSideToken,
      requested_token_use: 'on_behalf_of',
      scope: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read'
```

> This is my request body for the consent

Comment: If you are using **ClientID** and **ClientSecret** your value of **grant_type** will be **client_credentials**.

Comment: How did you request it, can you provide the code?

Comment: Which docs your are referring to? Could you please share more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your error message, I guess this should be caused by you not setting the request parameters correctly. You should put the request parameters in the **request body**.

[image]